# Composer install .zip could not be downloaded

Tags: composer, http-error-500, oauth, auth.json

When I run composer install I get the error message:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-invitation/magento-module-invitation-100.3.5.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
```

But I have auth.json in the `magento/` directory like https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud says.

```
{
"http-basic": {
    "repo.magento.com": {
        "username": "xxx",
        "password": "xxx"
}
```

}
}

I also tried to put the auth.json file in `~/.composer` to no avail.
Is there any way to test that my auth keys work? Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you running Magento commerce or Magento open source? if this is Magento open source why it is taking invitation module?